# How do I get the Good Work, Woody achievement?

Tags: achievements, jetpack-joyride

It says to run into the bottom obstacle three times in a row. I tried running into the lowest zapper I saw as soon as possible three times in a row and that didn't do it. I tried letting missiles hit me as I was walking and that didn't do it.

How do I get this achievement? Am I just missing something really simple?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to die three time by running into a low zapper obstacle without ever flying.
Just start a game and don't press anything (make sure you don't have a head start), most chances the first obstacle you'd hit will be a zapper (missiles don't appear that early), do that three times and the achievement is yours.

Comment: Awesome, it worked. Would've been nice if the achievement text mentioned it had to be the first bottom obstacle or I would've gotten this ages ago!

Answer (score 0):

Run into the bottom zapper, then play again. Repeat it three more times then congrats. Good Work, Woody.